# Convergence in Probability for a Sequence of Random Variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to solve the following:

Let $\{X_n, n ≥ 1\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with density
$f(x) = e^{−(x−a)}$, for $x ≥ a$ and $f(x) =0$, for $x < a$.
Set $Y_n = \min(X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n)$. Show that $Y_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ in probability.

So far I have that since $f(x) = e^{−(x−a)}$, for $x ≥ a$, then $F_X(x)=\int_a^x e^{-(x-a)} \, dx=1-e^{a-x}$.  Then since each $X_i$ in the sequence is iid, $F_{Y_{n}}(x)=(1-e^{a-x})^n$.  To prove convergence in probability I need $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|Y_{(n)}-a|\leq\varepsilon)=1$.

So,  $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|Y_{(n)}-a|\leq\varepsilon)=\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|Y_{(n)}|\leq\varepsilon + a)=\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{Y_n}(\varepsilon +a)$.
I can't get any further then this step in showing that the limit is $1$.  I'm not sure if my probability distribution function is wrong, but I end up getting $0$ instead of $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(Y_n \le x) = 1-\Pr(Y_n >x) = 1-\Pr(X_1>x\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n>x) \\[6pt]
= {} & 1 - \Big(\Pr(X_1>x)\Big)^n = 1-(e^{a-x})^n = 1 - e^{n(a-x)}. \\ {}
\end{align}

It is incorrect to say that $Y_n\le x$ if and only if $\Big( X_1 \le x\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n\le x \Big)$, but it is correct to say that $Y_n>x$ if and only if $\Big( X_1 > x\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n > x \Big)$.

Comment: When you substitute in for $Pr(X_1>x)$, shouldn't you use the CDF of X_1, not the PDF?  Did I compute the CDF incorrectly in my work above?  Also don't we need $1-e^{n(a-x)} \to 1$ to show convergence?  Doesn't this quantity diverge since as $e^{n(a-x)} \to \infty $as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @user75514 : Yes: I did indeed take $1$ minus the CDF. That's what that is.  $1-F_X(x) = 1-\Big(1-e^{a-x}\Big)$ $=e^{a-x}$ for $x>a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks, and in this case $x=\epsilon + a$, so $e^{n(a-x)}=e^{-n\epsilon}$ which tends to 0 as n tends to $\infty$.